# How to draw a line of certain length and direction?

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, line, direction

I want to create a line of certain length and direction.
What i mean by this is drawing a line from Point A to Point B.
Normally in Unity C# to draw a line from Point A to Point B is simply.

```
Debug.DrawLine(point_A, point_B);
```

The Diagram would be something like this

```
A----------------B
```

But i dont want something like this, i want it to draw from Point A to Point B but with a certain length. So i am guess we need the direction for this to work. But i dont know how to code it.

Here is a basic diagram of how i want it.

```
A--------        B
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What grade/year you are in (math is simple, but depending on you level one would need to provide different explanation - `point_A, point_A + (point_B - point_A) * desiredLength /abs(point_B - point_A)` )

Answer (score 0):

First of, it's not a good idea to use `Debug.DrawLine()` not for debuging. You should use the LineRenderer component.

Second: you have to create a vector that is the direction from point_A to point_B you do it like:

```
Vector3 difference = point_B - point_A;
```

Then get the end point of the line:

```
Vector3 endPoint = point_A + (difference.normalized * length);
```

Then do

```
GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(0, point_A);
GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, endPoint);
```